# What would cause MySql to have slow performance on a fresh install of Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, mysql

I have noticed slow MySQL performance on my Macbook Pro 2018.

Macbook 2018 System Specs:

- 15" MacBook Pro 2018
- 2,9 GHz 6‑Core Intel Core i9
- 32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
- 1 TB SSD

Tested using mysql-server, mariadb and percona-server with a tested loop of `1000 x SELECT` queries.

Result on mac with mojave: 17 seconds.
Result on same mac with VMware + ubuntu 18.04 on it: 6 seconds.

I did another test on other macbook pro with ubuntu installed on it.

Macbook 2017 System Specs:

- 15" MacBook Pro 2017
- 2,2 GHz 6‑Core Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
- 256 GB SSD

Tested using mariadb and percona-server with a tested loop of `1000 x SELECT` queries.

Result on mac with ubuntu: 9 seconds.

As you can see even VMware is faster as native mysql server. What would make mysql so slow?